# Import Eclipse workspace to netbeans (not regular Eclipse workspace)

Tags: c++, eclipse, import, netbeans-7

I downloaded NetBeans IDE 7.3.1 and want to port my C++ projects from Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version 2.0.0 (it's my first installation of both IDEs, so there were no earlier versions on my PC - Win 7 32Bit)

As I tried the steps from [Netbeans Support](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/import-eclipse.html)

I set up my Eclipse Workspace at E:\path. If I enter this path, according to

> **step 3:** 
>   *In the Workspace Location page of the wizard, select the Import Projects from Workspace radio button and specify the workspace location. Click Next.*

I am not able to go on importing because of the Error-Message:

```
*"E:\path" does not contain a regular Eclipse workspace.*
```

Does anyone have a clue of what's going on and / or know how to fix this? I stored all my Eclipse cpp projects in this folder by shifting them to subfolders like E:\path\Basics (Eclipse still recognizes the projects)

Comment: If one votes me downwards it would be nice to add a comment with suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you missed the import of the first sentence in your NetBeans support link. Here's the relevant portion with added emphasis...

> An enhanced support for importing Eclipse projects is available in the
>   NetBeans IDE. The Import Eclipse Project wizard enables you to use
>   NetBeans to ***work on Java desktop and web application projects***
>   that were created in Eclipse and MyEclipse.

You are trying to work on a C++ project and the wizard does not appear to be intended for that use.

Comment: I did read this, but I did not read it that way, as it is only possible with java. thanks for your suggestion (even more because a long time has passed now, since I asked :D).